# How to change the default grey color of the alert dialog box in android

Tags: android, colors

i am looking for ways to change the default color of alert box in android to different color like green or blue. please suggest me ways with exampls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there are you try the following.

1)using setview method of alertdialog to set the view and set the view background as per your choice.

2)you can set the your user defined theme and use it in constructor of your dialog.

3)extend dialog class and in oncreate method decorate your dialog box as per your need.

I just shared the idea with which you can achieve your need.For more info visit the following link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

cheers...

Comment: LayoutInglator inf = getSystemService(LayoutInflator);
View V = inf.inflate(yout layout id);
alertdialog.setView(v);

that done..